# Issues installing Angular

Tags: angular

Issues installing Angular.

When go to 'npm audit fix' following configuration / installation of;

npm install @angular/material@6.4.7 --save
npm install @angular/cdk@6.4.7 --save

### Display:

8 vulnerabilities (3 low, 3 moderate, 2 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

No longer able to display @ localhost:4200 without the following error being displayed;

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/obiora/Documents/Education/sustainability/conFusion/node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js'

Just in-case anyone is tempted to try and fix any one of the follwing vulnerabilities by using 'npm audit fix' - DON'T!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, consider reading the asking [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please revise your post

Comment: `Just in-case anyone is tempted to try and fix any one of the follwing vulnerabilities by using 'npm audit fix' - DON'T!` What's the meaning of that?

Comment: Angular installations: the installation has been audited to see if there were any conflicts / vulnerabilities in the package..it gave the user the option of fixing them; this in turn ended up erroring the installation..Additional conflicts have been found whilst installing and using angular, currently applicating it for a course on full-stack development..thats all!